# Page Layout I've created cannot be viewed by other users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, page-layout

I created and edited a page layout using SharePoint Designer 2010, but when others try to view the page layout they get a blank page (the one I created had a Calender, left nav etc. ). Even if they view a page created by my page layout, they can't see it (No calendar etc. ). I on the other hand am able to see and use the page layout.

I've noticed in comparison with the other page layouts that work (everyone can view and edit), that in SharePoint designer the layout says modified by the user, but for mine it says modified by SHAREPOINT/system. Did I create the layout wrongly ? how come only I can see the layout, while others can't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All page layouts must be Checked In *and* Published in order for others to see them.